# Multiple Reverse-Relations in Django-REST-FrameWork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Models:

```
class Client(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)

class Phone(Model):
    client = ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=CASCADE)
    number = CharField(max_length=50)
```

Serializers:

```
class PhoneSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    number = CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('number')

class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer, GlobalObjectMixin):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = CharField(required=True)

    phone = PhoneSerializer(required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if 'phone' in validated_data:
            phones = validated_data.pop('phone')

        client = Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
        phone = Phone.objects.create(
            client_id=client.id,
            **phones
        )
        return client

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'phone', 'phone_set')
```

Problem:

> I can't add multiple phones while creating the Client, if I provide
>   only one Phone for Client, I can create and retrieve that Client with
>   no problem, but if I add multiple Phones while creating the Client, I
>   got an empty list instead of a list of dicts with Phones.

PS: I'm making requests via postman, I provide Phone while creating Client like: phone.number : 1234567

Comment: Show your requesting method/screenshot using postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default reverse lookup for ForeignKey is `model_set` or `phone_set` so you need to rename `phone` field to `phone_set`, also you need to provide `many=True` argument to serialize set of objects:

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer, GlobalObjectMixin):
     id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
     title = CharField(required=True)

     phone_set = PhoneSerializer(required=False, many=True)

     def create(self, validated_data):
         if 'phone_set' in validated_data:
             phones = validated_data.pop('phone_set')
```

In this case you need to provide data in following format:

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "phone_set": {
                    "number": 1234567
                 }
}
```

Comment: Here is the problem, I already tried that, and it works only for trieving, but doesn't work for creating !!! Error: create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing the same but via PostMan, after your answer I typed: phone_set.number with value in PostMan body, but validated_data came as empty

Comment: @Madi7 try to send it as raw data with type json.

Comment: I tried, now thanks to your advice I'm able to create multiple Phones for Client via raw, however when retrieving that Client, it returns only one Phone instead if multiple ((

Comment: @Madi7 are you sure you have many phones for client? Did you check in DB? Also it would be good to remove `phone` from `fields` list: `fields = ('id', 'title', 'phone_set')`

Comment: You were right all along ! I got a single Phone when retrieve because I didn't unpack the list called 'phones', as a result only one Phone object was created for that Client, I just done something like: for dict in phones: Phone.objects.create(client_id=client.id, number=dict['number']) so everything works great now, many thanks to you ! I couldn't achieve this without you !!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = CharField(required=True)
    phone = PhoneSerializer(required=False, many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_list = []
        if 'phone' in validated_data:
            phone_list = validated_data.pop('phone', [])
        client = Client.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for phone in phone_list:
            Phone.objects.create(client=client, number=phone['number'])

        return client

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'phone',)
```

and try this `raw json`

```
{
    "title": "my title",
    "phone": [
        {
                    "number": 789123
                 },
                 {
                    "number": 456963
                 }
                 ]
}
```